# missing section dot?

Tags: sectioning

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%twoside yaz iki taraflı için
\usepackage[top=2.5 cm, bottom=2.5 cm, left=4 cm, right=2.5 cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\begin{document}
\section{sec1}
test      
\subsection{subsec2}
test
\end{document}
```

There must be a dot after section number with \titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad} but not. What's the problem?

Comment: Why not use just `\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
  {\thesection.\quad}
  {1em}
  {}`?

Comment: I tried but didn't work.

Comment: You want it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoEYX.png ? I just added `.\quad` after `\thesection`...

Comment: It work but
there is unnecessary space between number and section and in ToC there isn't any section dot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want it like this:

> [image]

The unnecessary space you said in the comments is because the fourth mandatory argument to `\titleformat` is the spacing, which you already had set to `1em`, so adding a `\quad` doubled it.

To add the dot after the number in the ToC you can redefine `\numberline`:

```
\let\LTXnumberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\LTXnumberline{#1.}}
```

this is a low level trick that works with the standard classes. But it will probably not work if you use another class or some ToC styling package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%twoside yaz iki taraflı için
\usepackage[top=2.5 cm, bottom=2.5 cm, left=4 cm, right=2.5 cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\let\LTXnumberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\LTXnumberline{#1.}}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
  {\thesection.}
  {1em}% this gives a \quad of space
  {}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{sec1}
test      
\subsection{subsec2}
test
\end{document}
```